# Extracting POST response data returns NOT_FOUND

Tags: jmeter

I was hoping someone may be able to help with the following issue I have.

I have a 'HTTP Request' sampler that makes a POST request.  The response data for this request as per the results tree is:

```
<script>window.document.location.href='handler.ashx?act=wzfin\x26req=nav\x26mop=requirements!new_finish_wiz\x26pk=0c86ea74-c067-4bcf-a49d-be7d0e420fbf';</script>
```

I want to grab the value for the pk parameter in the response URL above and store in a variable called REQUIREMENT_ID.  I have set up a 'Regular Expression Extractor' for the sampler and set it up as per below:

- Apply to: Main Sample Only
- Field to Check: Response message
- Reference Name: REQUIREMENT_ID
- Regular Expression: (?<=pk=)(.*)(?=\')
- Template: $1$
- Match No: 1
- Default Value: NOT_FOUND

However, when I run this, NOT_FOUND is being returned.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

`[Regular Expression Extractor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F36HS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regular expression to this `<script>.+pk=(.*?)'`

And change your field to check to `Body`

[image]

Comment: This appear to work when running through the RegExp Tester in the 'Results Tree'.  But still returns NOT_FOUND when I run the test so I think the problem may lie outside the regex.

Comment: Make sure you are not using any other regex with the same name after this one, also check if the response is fine

Comment: There are no other regular expression extractors being used and the response is coming through fine when looking in the results tree.

Comment: Also change the Field to check to Body, i think that's the problem

Comment: That did the trick thanks.  I'm sure I had already tried that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: ".*pk=(.*?)'"

Not to sure why you way doesn't work to be honest.

Comment: This doesn't seem to return anything.  However, I think the problem may lie outside of the regex.  After entering a simple regexp NOT_FOUND was still being returned.

Comment: Just stating the obvious but you can see the "PK=Value" in the response data ?

Comment: yes, the pk value is populating ok, an example of the latest response: <script>window.document.location.href='handler.ashx?act=wzfin\x26req=nav\x26mop=requirements!new_finish_wiz\x26pk=5e3a0551-2db2-4584-80c4-1c0b2be828af';</script>